# Debug Python with VSCode Remote - Containers

Tags: python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

I have running container with Python app and WSGI configuration that accepts bunch of GET parameters. The goal is requesting the app through browser(or curl) and get working breakpoints using `VSCode Remote - Containers` extension.

Host OS: Fedora 28, Container OS: CentOS 7

Docker details:

```
- Docker v18.09.9
- No Dockerfile(just running container)
- Docker network using
- Container IP is 172.18.0.2
- App directory is mounted from host filesystem
```

App details:

```
- No frameworks
- Just Python3 with several modules
- Virtual environment using
```

IDE details:

```
- VSCode v1.38.1
- Remote - Containers extension
- Python extension(installed in attached container also)
```

In VSCode I can `Attach to Running Container`, then open app directory that mounted earlier and edit code, install packages etc. It's ok, but I stuck with debug configuration, predefined items(Flask, Django etc) don't match my workflow.

How to tweak launch.json file for that purpose?

Comment: You can start to use open folder in container feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-try-a-dev-container

Comment: I've tried vscode-remote-try-python, it works but does not match my case. I have own container that configured for specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify which web framework you're using. I'm using pyramid and debugging works just fine.

Here's how I did it:

- As you said, attach to the running container
- Use "Open folder..." to open the path where the sources of the app are located. You should NOT add more folders to the workspace, that will not work.
- Install the Python extension in the running container. If you open the extensions bar, you should have a button saying `Install in attached container...`
- From the command palette select `View: Show Debug`
- Click on the gears icon in the debug configuration and you should be able to select `Python` as language.
- Either way you'll end up with a `launch.json` file that you can edit.

This is what I have in the file, for Pyramid:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid Application",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pyramid.scripts.pserve",
            "args": [
                "--reload",
                "--server-name",
                "docker",
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "pyramid": true,
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the `"justMyCode": false,`. This is quite important if your projects has dependencies from other local projects that get installed when you build the container.

For example, if you have in the requirements file a reference to your git repository, that will be installed in a system directory and by default the debugger will not step into the functions there. This option makes it so that the debugger gets into it.

Comment: As specified in question I don't use any framework.
All what I need  -  just WSGI callable with couple of imported packages and Apache mod_wsgi for request handling.

Comment: If you don't use any framework it should be even easier, just replace the `pserve` command with whatever you use to launch your app

Comment: I specified full path to WSGI callable and got error:`/home/www/sile/.venv/bin/python /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.44104/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 37153 -m /home/www/sile/wsgi/app.py 
E00000.174: Error determining module path for sys.argv`

Comment: Is [program](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_program) more suitable for my case?

Comment: It looks like that, but it's still not clear what your use case actually is. If you were not in a container, what command would you use to launch your app? Also, it looks like you put the full path in the `module` entry of the launch.json file, which is not what you want. If on the command line all you do is `python app.py`, all you need is remove the `module` entry and put `"args": ["app.py"]`. You basically need to reproduce the command line that you use

Comment: I launch the app in browser on Host: `http://site/app?param1=value1&param2=value2`. Then, inside of Container, Apache mod_wsgi runs `/home/www/site/wsgi/app.py`. Use case is to get working breakpoints.

Comment: What I meant is, what command line do you use to launch the server?

Comment: It seems my case is not standard. The server is Apache in container, i don't launch other development servers.

Comment: Your case is very standard, if you don't know the command line, you can look into your `Dockerfile`